# RVM pkg install checksum error

Tags: ruby, rvm, zlib

```
root@li417-132:~# rvm pkg install zlib
Fetching zlib-1.2.7.tar.gz to /usr/local/rvm/archives
There is no checksum for 'http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/libpng/zlib-1.2.7.tar.gz' or 'zlib-1.2.7.tar.gz', it's not possible to validate it.
If you wish to continue with unverified download add '--verify-downloads 1' after the command.


Please note that it's required to reinstall all installed rubies:

    rvm reinstall all --force
    rvm all-gemsets do rvm gemset pristine
```

A weird problem happened today, other linux boxes i've setup a few days ago never did this, but today i cannot install any rvm packages, and adding '--verify-downloads 1' after the command seems to have no effect at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this is a new change in RVM, you can make it work with:

```
rvm --verify-downloads 1 pkg install zlib
```

The best solution would be adding md5 / sha512 for zlib so it could be validated

The command parsing was fixed already, udate rvm to make it working:

```
rvm get head
```

---

## Deprecation warning:

`rvm pkg` is deprecated by **autolibs**:

```
rvm get stable
rvm autolibs enable
rvm install ruby
```

RVM will automatically use system package manager to install missing libraries and configure ruby with proper compilation settings if needed - on OSX RVM detects macports, homebrew, fink and if non found installs macports to handle the libraries installation.

Comment: when you run the above command it will add entry in `~/.rvm/user/md5`, copy it and add it here (Edit in place should work): https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/config/md5

Comment: The RVM message is really misleading. One would interpret AFTER, like, after the entire command.

Comment: @Zequez this is already fixed and it should work at any point of the command line.

Comment: @Marek, you need update rvm first `rvm get head && rvm reload`, if you have still problems - open issue at github or contact me on #rvm irc channel.

Comment: @mpapis thanks, i will try, but i did a fresh install today and still had to google up that problem.

Comment: @Marek the problem as having to specify `--verify-downloads 1` or the problem it does not work on the end of command line?

Comment: I used this `--verify-downloads 1` tip to successfully install Ruby 1.9.3: `rvm --verify-downloads 1 install 1.9.3`

Comment: I find these Stack overflow recommendations to "rvm get head" highly disturbing.  I would only do that if "rvm get stable" isn't working.  But is this a production box?  GET STABLE